# Include template from another template in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, sails.js

I have created a sails.js template: **templates/box.ejs**

```
<div id="<%= box_id%>" class="<%= box_class %>">
    <% if(box_title || box_title_icon) {%>
        <div class="header">
            <% include icon%> <---- HERE
            <span class="title"><%= box_title %></span>
            <hr>
        </div>
    <% } %>
    <div class="content">
        <%= typeof box_content == 'function' ? box_content() : box_content%>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this template I try to include another template file called `icon`.

But I get this error generated by sails grunt JST task:

```
error: Grunt ::  Aborted due to warnings.
 Running "jst:dev" (jst) task

>> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Warning: JST failed to compile. Use --force to continue.
```

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<%- include icon.ejs %>
```

You need a "-" after the ejs open tag and better add a extension to your filename

Comment: If I add an extension, the server cannot render the page anymore. If I add a `-` it doesn't have any effect. Maybe I didn't try both at the same time...

Comment: If I add an extension, the server cannot render the page anymore - what error you get? Maybe you have a problem with your relativ path? Include always uses the path of the document you used "include" into

Comment: I know it uses relative path but it never worked using the extension. I basically get a `not found` error

Comment: Ah than you maybe have mistake with your path. try use the absolute path (e.g. /var/user/myapp/templates/..)